# Change label color when input has .ng-invalid

Tags: css, angular

My form is built as a **template driven**.

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="guitar" class="col-sm-6">Guitar:</label>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input id="guitar" type="text">
        <p *ngIf="template driven template ngIf">Warning!</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

When in `<input id="guitar">` I enter invalid characters, then `<input>` will get the style:

`border: 2px solid red` from:

```
input.form-control.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

and shows `<p>Warning!</p>`.

It works great.

Is it possible to change the color:

```
<label for="guitar">Guitar:</label>
```

to **red** when `<p>Warning!</p>` is displayed and `<input>` has a **border**?

Comment: My error template like this - "when the input has less than 10 characters, show <p>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your own question : if you have this condition that displays your warning message

```
*ngIf="template driven template ngIf"
```

Why not simply apply this condition to your input ?

```
<input id="guitar" type="text" [class.red]="template driven template ngIf">
.red { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only achieve this by grabbing a handle of the input's `ngModel` directive instance by

```
<input ... [(ngModel)]="..." #whateverInput="ngModel" ... />
```

and then for the label use

```
<label for="..." [class.ng-invalid]="whateverInput.invalid" ...></label>
```

(Then style the label as if it was also `.ng-invalid`)

One can also think of a way of automating this with a directive, but haven't given it enough thought.

Hope this helps!